# Align component with image

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an android layout with an imageview as a background and  components like buttons and editText on top. This works nicely with a constraint layout but when i change the device dimensions the components are misplaced. Is there any way to align the components to the imageView, so that they're always at the right spot, independent of orientation and dimensions?

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/character_sheet" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="111dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.945"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.272" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide you're xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found a way to do this now.
First you need a ConstraintLayout, then you put another ConstraintLayout(Lets call this "2nd layer") inside it with margins of 0 on all sides and set the layout width and height to wrap_content. You now put your ImageView into this the 2nd layer and turn adjustViewBounds and cropToPadding on. You also set the margins of the imageView to 0 and set the layout width and height to wrap_content. If you now want to add a component and want to have it align with an object in your image, you put guidelines in a rectangular fashion around said object. After that you can add your component and tell it to snap to the guidelines. The component will now snap to that object regardless of screen size or orientation.

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/character_sheet" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.94" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.42" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.13" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many devices have different screen sizes and also pixel densities.  So when you change a device and only have one layout design, if the device is a different screen size/pixel density from what you originally created the layout for, the way it looks will be different.

Check out this document: http://www.androiddocs.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

BUT, dig deeper into research by searching in google "android studio layout design for different screen sizes" and start digesting all the info. Give yourself some time, don't worry too much about how fast you learn, but that you make progress towards learning.